# Nested components with Angular 1.5 and latest ui-router version

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to use the new 1.5 router and angular components kissing routes, but I arises a problem with nested components

```
.state('custom', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/custom,
    component: 'custom'
})
    .state('custom.children', {
        url: '/children',
        component: 'customChildren'
    })
```

`customChildren` Component has this template:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
<div>
    <h1>My Title</h1>
    <div ui-view class='settings-content' 
        custom-children-attr='$ctrl.childrenValue'>
    </div>
</div>
```

`custom`Component:

```
class CustomController {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }

  $onInit() {
      this.childrenValue = 'test';
  }

  $onChanges(changes) {
    ...
  }
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .component('custom', {
    templateUrl: 'custom.html',
    controller: CustomController
  });
```

`customSon` is this:

```
class CustomChildrenController {
    constructor(...) {
        ...
    }

    $onInit() {
        ...
    }

    $onChanges(changes) {
        ...
    }
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .component('customChildren', {
        templateUrl: 'custom-children.html',
        controller: CustomChildrenController,
        bindings: {
            customChildrenAttr: '<'
        }
    });
```

When I go to `/custom/children`, I can not get the value of `customChildrenAttr`. How I can get the `customChildrenAttr` binding? I try with resolve and other things but I don't get it to work .

Comment: Please provide the `custom` component as well - what is the value of `$ctrl.childrenValue`?